# frappe.get_url return http:// but not https://

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I am using frappe v14, however, when I use frappe.get_url in jinja2, it return me http://xxxx, but not https://xxxxx, may I know if I miss any setup. I am using https://xxxx for visiting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your site config should have an SSL certificate. To set follow the steps mention here https://frappeframework.com/docs/v14/user/en/bench/guides/configuring-https

Answer (score 0):

You may have setup ssl manually (not through bench) for your site. You can add a rule in your NGINX config to auto upgrade requests (if you have https setup).

Another way is to debug get_url and figure out which key is missing to be set in the site_config so that Frappe can handle the rest for you.

ref: [Adding a redirect rule in NGINX](https://serverfault.com/a/337893/581425)